# How to make split function return TRUE for empty cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to make the C5 returns 1 (True). And return False only if * is in the A cell.

For that, I believe the Split function must not jut ignore empty cells, but return TRUE when it dont contain the keyword *.

[image: Table]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to make the C5 returns 1 (True). And return False only if * is in the A cell.

If this is your goal, then your title is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The easiest way to do this is using [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en).

```
=NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\*"))
```

This formula will return FALSE if `*` appears anywhere in cell A2 and TRUE otherwise. If you want to return 0 and 1 instead, use any of these:

```
=--NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\*"))
=1*NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\*"))
=0+NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\*"))
=N(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\*")))
```

Comment: That if instead of * it was a string of words? like: =NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\some words"))

Comment: that should work but remove the backslash.